# UPDATE with JOIN not SELECTing expected value

Tags: sql-update, mariadb, where-clause

I'm trying to UPDATE a temporary transaction table with values from a holdings table. The fields I want to get are from the holding with the lowest date that is higher than the transaction date.

When I use below SELECT statement, the right values are shown:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM transaction_tmp tt
    JOIN holdings h
        ON tt.isin = h.isin
            AND tt.portfolio = h.portfolio
    WHERE h.start_date > tt.tr_date
    ORDER BY h.start_date
    LIMIT 1
```

However, when I use below UPDATE statement, incorrect values are selected/updated in transaction_tmp:

```
UPDATE transaction_tmp tt
    JOIN holdings h
        ON tt.isin = h.isin
            AND tt.portfolio = h.portfolio
    SET
        tt.next_id = h.id,
        tt.next_start_date = h.start_date
    WHERE h.start_date > tt.tr_date
    ORDER BY h.start_date
    LIMIT 1
```

I'm thinking the WHERE statement is not working appropriately, but unfortunately I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Appreciate any help here!
-Joost

Comment: Pls clarify if you use mysql or mariadb because they behave differently in this particular case.

Comment: Are there two rows with the same `start_date`?

Comment: Apologies, should've mentioned I'm using mariadb10

Comment: @RickJames, there are no two rows with the same start_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work using a subquery

```
UPDATE transaction_tmp tt
JOIN  (
  SELECT h.*
  FROM transaction_tmp tt
  JOIN holdings h
      ON tt.isin = h.isin
          AND tt.portfolio = h.portfolio
  WHERE h.start_date > tt.tr_date
  ORDER BY h.start_date
  LIMIT 1

) tx on ON tt.isin = tx.isin
          AND tt.portfolio = tx.portfolio

 SET
    tt.next_id = tx.id,
    tt.next_start_date = tx.start_date
```

Comment: This causes a syntax error, probably because I'm using mariadb

Comment: show me the exact error message  ..anyway i have updated the answer  adding the SET clause

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised your syntax works.  The MySQL documentation is pretty clear that `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` are only allowed when there is a *single* table reference:

> ```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
>     SET assignment_list
>     [WHERE where_condition]
>     [ORDER BY ...]
>     [LIMIT row_count]
> ```

They are not allowed for the multiple table version of `UPDATE`:

> ```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
>     SET assignment_list
>     [WHERE where_condition]
> ```
>
> . . .
>   For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

I get an error if I try such syntax.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps the OP uses mariadb v10.3.2 or newer, which allows this. I have long been saying, if somebody uses mariadb, then the question should not be tagged with mysql.

Comment: @Shadow . . . If it were MariaDB, wouldn't the query do what the OP expects?